# If search on model has no hits, invoke javascript file

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

I make an search on an model:

```
def self.search(search)
if search
    where('Bezeichnung LIKE?', "%#{search}%")
else
   all
end
end
```

What i would like to change, is that when the search has no hits it fires an javascript file in icd/index.js.erb

Index.js.erb:

```
$('#chapter_list').html("<%= escape_javascript(render(:partial => 'icd1')) %>");
```

How can i do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably this class method (self.search) is on a model. Since your controllers are where you return responses from, you'd need to have your controller respond with javascript code.

Something like:

```
def index
  results = Model.search(params[:search])
  respond_to |format| do
    if results
      format.html { render 'index.html.erb' }
    else
      format.js { render 'index.js.erb' }
    end
  end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

i would do something like this, i would create another model method, like this:

Model:

```
def checkSearch(search)
  if search
     where('Bezeichnung LIKE?', "%#{search}%")
  end
end
```

controller

```
@checker= Model.checkSearch(search)
```

in the view you can check if @checker is different from null and redner the partial

I know this aproach will query the database twice, but is a start.

more thought on it you can return an array in you first model method with a bollean in the first position and the active record object in the second one.

hope i gave you some direction!